# Custom tab shows up blank (no content) with the words "I'm a Teapot"

Tags: facebook, tabs

I recently created a Facebook custom tab for a organization page and followed all the developer's instructions. I have a secure site, made sure all the dimensions are correct, etc. 
For some reason, the tab shows up completely blank, no content. Sometimes it simply has the words "I am a teapot", which I found out was an error code...What does this error mean and how do I fix it???

Comment: Check browser's console for any errors

Comment: What kind of errors am I looking for? Sorry, I am a beginner at this...

Comment: Your application is not loading in the page tab right? So there must be some error, you can check for errors in the browser console (in chrome: ctrl+shift+J)

Comment: O ok so the console says that "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 418 (Bad Request)" and then shows the url for the site from which I was attempting to pull content from...Any idea how to fix errors #418? I have been googling all day and am still not sure..Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure. But are you sure, the canvas url is working fine? Can you give me the actual app url?

Comment: So I think the problem was that Facebook requires a secure url as well as a regular url for the external site from which I pull content. I just took the regular url and added an "s" after "http", but apparently this does not work...I need to find a way to make the whole site secure

Answer (score 0):

See, your actual url to the application that is hosted on some domain, should be **SSL** certified.

Eg: If your url was http://my-app.com, then https://my-app.com must also work, else it will not be published to the facebook!

Comment: Right so I think the only way to make the site I am using secure is if I upgrade the site to a business one...Do you know of any other way to secure a site? or of a website host that is already secure from the start?

Comment: If your site supports `https`, it will work for you. PS dint forget to accept the answer if works. Good luck :)